# Counting values of a stack using a javascript algorithm

Tags: javascript, stack

I need help figuring out how to make a JavaScript algorithm that count the values of a stack, I am given 3 custom methods

stack - a Stack object containing zero or more values.

.pop() which pops the top value of the stack

.push() which pushes a value on to the stack

.peek() which shows me the top value of the stack without modifying the stack

I tried simply returning the length of said stack like so

```
function countValues(stack) {
  return stack.length
}
```

but i get back undefined thus having no success

this is the stack class that was used to implement the custom methods

```
class Stack {

  constructor(...values) {

    const data = {};

    let index = 0;

    this.push = function (value) {
      if (arguments.length < 1) {
        throw new TypeError('stack.push() requires a value argument');
      }
      if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
        throw new TypeError('stack.push(value) received undefined');
      }
      data[index] = value;
      index++;
    };

    this.pop = function () {
      const last = index - 1;
      if (last < 0) return;
      const value = data[last];
      delete data[last];
      index = last;
      return value;
    };

    this.peek = function () {
      const last = index - 1;
      if (last < 0) return;
      return data[last];
    };

    this.print = function () {
      if (index === 0) {
        return 'Stack { <empty> }';
      }
      let output = ' }';
      let last = index - 1;
      for (; last > 0; last--) {
        output = ' <- ' + JSON.stringify(data[last]) + output;
      }
      output = JSON.stringify(data[last]) + output;
      return 'Stack { ' + output;
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      this.push(values[i]);
    }

    Object.freeze(this);

  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: its a Stack object containing zero or more values, im not totally sure if that's what you refer to by how its being implemented

Comment: We as outsiders have no clue how the `stack` data structure is implemented. We don't know anything at all about it except that it contains values. We don't know how iterate through the elements to count them. There must be some information available on how this task can be achieved. You can pop every element, but surely you don't want to empty the stack when you count the elements.

Comment: @poopmachine, do post some, reference code about your stack object.

Comment: i updated the post with the stack class code, i hope this can help

Comment: Answer now updated to use the code you provided

Comment: @poopmachine also, just for future reference, if you can include code (as you have) then it will pretty much always help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Stack {
  constructor(...values) {

    const data = {};

    let index = 0;

    this.push = function(value) {
      if (arguments.length < 1) {
        throw new TypeError('stack.push() requires a value argument');
      }
      if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
        throw new TypeError('stack.push(value) received undefined');
      }
      data[index] = value;
      index++;
    };

    this.pop = function() {
      const last = index - 1;
      if (last < 0) return;
      const value = data[last];
      delete data[last];
      index = last;
      return value;
    };

    this.peek = function() {
      const last = index - 1;
      if (last < 0) return;
      return data[last];
    };

    this.print = function() {
      if (index === 0) {
        return 'Stack { <empty> }';
      }
      let output = ' }';
      let last = index - 1;
      for (; last > 0; last--) {
        output = ' <- ' + JSON.stringify(data[last]) + output;
      }
      output = JSON.stringify(data[last]) + output;
      return 'Stack { ' + output;
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      this.push(values[i]);
    }

    Object.freeze(this);
  }
}

const myStack = new Stack(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// Here's an easy but not so good way:
function countValues1(stack) {
  return Array.from(stack.print()).filter(x => x === "<").length + 1;
}

// Here's another way, but it mutates the stack:
function countValues2(stack) {
  let count = 0;
  while (true) {
    if (stack.pop() === undefined) {
      break;
    }
    count++;
  }
  
  return count;
}

console.log(countValues1(myStack));
console.log(countValues2(myStack));
```

Without knowing exactly how stack works, or specifically what you need (are you allowed to modify the stack implementation? are you allowed to mutate the contents of the stack?) we'll struggle for a good answer, but the above should help get you maybe slightly closer perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you doing a length function manually.
You should check how you declared your stack, `.length` is supposed to be working.

```
function countValues(stack) {
  const tempStack = stack;
  var length=0;

  while(tempStack.pop()!=undefined){
    length++;
  }
  return length;
}
```

This function allows you to run it and still keeping your data in the original stack.

Answer (score -2):

`length` is a getter, which is essentially a function posing as a property. It will just return `undefined` if you call it on an object that doesn't implement it. If the exercise -- I assume that's what it is -- says you can only use the abovementioned methods, then you can't use `object.length`.